# Keeping Shemittah "When you enter the land"?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, shmita, behar

The mitzvah of Shemittah is introduced in the following way in Parshas Behar ([Vayikra 25:1-4](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.25:1-4?ven=The_Contemporary_Torah,_Jewish_Publication_Society,_2006&vhe=Miqra_according_to_the_Masorah&lang=bi&aliyot=0)):

> וַיְדַבֵּ֤ר ה' אֶל־מֹשֶׁ֔ה בְּהַ֥ר סִינַ֖י לֵאמֹֽר׃ דַּבֵּ֞ר אֶל־בְּנֵ֤י יִשְׂרָאֵל֙ וְאָמַרְתָּ֣ אֲלֵהֶ֔ם **כִּ֤י תָבֹ֙אוּ֙ אֶל־הָאָ֔רֶץ** אֲשֶׁ֥ר אֲנִ֖י נֹתֵ֣ן לָכֶ֑ם וְשָׁבְתָ֣ה הָאָ֔רֶץ שַׁבָּ֖ת לַה'׃ שֵׁ֤שׁ שָׁנִים֙ תִּזְרַ֣ע שָׂדֶ֔ךָ וְשֵׁ֥שׁ שָׁנִ֖ים תִּזְמֹ֣ר כַּרְמֶ֑ךָ וְאָסַפְתָּ֖ אֶת־תְּבוּאָתָֽהּ׃ וּבַשָּׁנָ֣ה הַשְּׁבִיעִ֗ת שַׁבַּ֤ת שַׁבָּתוֹן֙ יִהְיֶ֣ה לָאָ֔רֶץ שַׁבָּ֖ת לַה' שָֽׂדְךָ֙ לֹ֣א תִזְרָ֔ע וְכַרְמְךָ֖ לֹ֥א תִזְמֹֽר׃
>
> Hashem spoke to Moshe on Mount Sinai: Speak to the Children of Israel and say to them: **When you enter the land** that I will give to you, the land shall observe a sabbath of Hashem: Six years you may sow your field and six years you may prune your vineyard and gather in the yield. But in the seventh year the land shall have a sabbath of complete rest, a sabbath of Hashem: you shall not sow your field or prune your vineyard.

So the Torah says expressly that this injunction starts when they enter the land. But when you think about it, this didn't take effect upon them entering the land! In fact it only happened in the 21st year?!

We know from sefer Yehoshua that Bnei Yisrael spent 7 years conquering the land and then another 7 splitting up the land, which would mean by the time they actually got round to keeping Shemittah it was the third round of seven years - in which case how do we understand the clause in Behar which says that it will be kept expressly "when you enter the land"?

Comment: Have you compared with the other כי תבאו אל הארץs?

Comment: The simple meaning of the verse is that once you enter the land, you become obligated to start counting the seven year cycle.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find any meforshim who were bothered by this. The Gra writes in [Aderes Eliyahu db"h כי תבאו](https://www.sefaria.org/Aderet_Eliyahu%2C_Leviticus.25.2.1?vhe=Aderet_Eliyahu,_Halberstadt,_1860&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) that "כי תבאו אל הארץ" comes to exclude a hava amina that shemitta applies to Ever haYarden. He then goes on to learn out that the counting of the years of the shemitta (and yovel) cycle only starts once all the land has been fully distributed, from the words "שדך וכרמך" in the subsequent pasuk.

With the two psukim together, it therefore (according to the Gra) becomes clear that the counting only starts later, and that "כי תבאו אל הארץ" is not meant to be understood literally that they keep shemitta the second they enter Eretz Yisroel.

See my boldings in the below quote from the Aderes Eliyahu linked above.

> **יכול משבאו לעבר הירדן ת"ל אל הארץ ארץ המיוחדת**. יכול משבאו לעמון ומואב ת"ל אשר אני נתן לכם ולא לעמון ומואב. יכול משכבשו אעפ"י שלא חלקו חלקו למשפחות ולא חלקו לבתי אבות או שחלקו לבתי אבות ואין כל א' מכיר את חלקו יכול יהיו חייבים בשמיטה **ת"ל שדך כרמך שיהא כל ח' מכיר את שדהו ואת כרמו**. נמצאת אתה אומר כיון שעברו ישראל את הירדן נתחייבו בחלה ובערלה ובחדש. הגיע ששה עשר בניסן נתחייבו בעומר. שהו חמשים יום נתחייבו בשתי הלחם. שהו ארבעה עשר שנים נתחייבו במעשרות. התחילו מונים לשמיטה. לעשרים ואחת עשו שמיטה. לששים ושלש עשו יובל [פי' דהיינו שהתחילה שנת היובל והא דאמר לעשרים וא' עשו שמיטה דהיינו סוף שנת השמיטה וליובל קרי התחלתו משום דשמיטה משמט בסופו ויובל בתחלתו] ושבתה הארץ. יכול אף לחפור בורות שיחין ומערות ת"ל שדך לא תזרע כו' אין לי אלא זריעה וזימור. עידור ניכוש וכיסוח ושאין מזבלין כו' ושאין מקרסמין מניין תלמוד לומר שדך לא כו' כרמך לא כו' כל מלאכה שבשדך וכל מלאכה שבכרמך יכול לא יקשקש תחת הזתים ולא ימלא את הנקעים שתחת הזתים ולא יעשה עוגיות בין אילן לאילן חבירו ת"ל שדך לא תזרע כרמך לא תזמר זריעה וזימור בכלל היתה ולמה יצאו להקיש אליה ולומר לך מה זריעה וזימור שהן עבודה בשדה וכרם אף אין לי אלא דברים שהם עבודה בשדה ובכרם [פי' וקישקוש תחת הזתים אינה עבודה אלא בכרם] יכול אף שנת היובל עולה מן המנין תלמוד לומר שש שנים תזרע שדך שנים שאתה זורע עולה מן המנין ואין שנת היובל עולה למנין שני שבוע מניין לאורז ודוחן ופרגין ולשומשמין שהשרישו לפני ר"ה שכונסין בשביעית ת"ל ואספת כו':

Comment: +1 Thank you I appreciate the answer!

Comment: It would seem the Chizkuni spells out a similar idea - https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.25.2?ven=The_Contemporary_Torah,_Jewish_Publication_Society,_2006&vhe=Miqra_according_to_the_Masorah&lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Chizkuni%2C_Leviticus.25.2.1&ven2=Chizkuni,_translated_and_annotated_by_Eliyahu_Munk&vhe2=Chizkuni&lang2=bi